# Correcting .csv file with CLRF between delimiters

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a .csv file with | as delimiter but without a text qualifier.
Some columns contain text with a line break CRLF and since Excel needs LF to differentiate between EOL CRLF and new line LF within a cell I cant see all rows as they should be.

Any idea of how I would be able to correct this?

26 Headers in total, the last header contains a file path and ends with }.filextension or NULL

```
Header1|Header2|Header3 CRLF
Text1|Text2|Text3 CRLF
Text1|Te CRLF
xt2|Text3 CRLF
Text1|Text2|Text3 CRLF

Header1|Header2|Header3 CRLF
Text1|Text2|Text3 CRLF
Text1|Text2|Text3 CRLF
Text1|Text2|Text3 CRLF
```

I was thinking about removing all CRLF with Notepad++ and with regex add only a CRLF after the last 26th Header. But since the last Header is either }.fileextension or NULL I don't know how to separate it from the start of the next row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to check that the right amount of delimiters exist before encountering the `CRLF` so something like this for the search:

```
(CRLF([^|]+\|){0,1}[^|]+)(CRLF)
```

and this for the replace:

```
$1LF
```

https://regex101.com/r/U3JvZZ/1/

My regex will work for the exact sample input which you have provided but when you go to do this against your real file then replace `CR` with `\r`, `LF` with `\n`, and `{0,1}` with `{0,24}`.

Comment: This worked...until I noticed there are as well rows with multiple CRLF. So the column text is so long, it has like 4-5 CRLF between the | delimiter.

Comment: @matze You should consider expanding your example to include these types of things...

Comment: the .csv file has around 53k rows ....didn't noticed it. Thank you so far, I will completely check the file for pattern first.

Comment: @matze Check for things like `Text1|"Te|xt2"|Text3 CRLF` as well because it indicates that a pipe is literally in the cell data rather than acting as a delimiter. If this exists then things are going to be really tough.

Comment: @matze Any luck?

Comment: Ok, so the .csv doesn't have any text qualifier at all and after looking through, only the second header, the "Description" column has this extra CRLF. Probably because the description text was getting too long. So CRLF's are only end of line and in the 2nd of 26 headers. The example you suggested to check occurs only once, i corrected it manually.